# 月末の日付を取得したいが、意図した結果にならない

Tags: php, laravel

リクエストパラーメータ `year = 2022`, `month = 6` から月初と月末の日付を取得しようとしたところ、以下のような結果になってしまいました。

月末の日付を正しく取得したいのですがどうすれば良いですか？

**現状のコード:**

```
$start_date = date($year."-".$month."-01");
$end_date   = date($year."-".$month."-t");

log::debug("終了日の確認");
log::debug($end_date);
```

**実行結果:**

```
[2022-05-23 21:51:25] local.DEBUG: 2022-6-31
```

Answer (score 1):

`$year."-".$month."-t"` は `2022-6-t` なのだから当然です。

`date`の1つめの引数はフォーマット、2つめの引数はUnixタイムスタンプで、2つめの引数を与えない場合のデフォルトは現在の時刻のUnixタイムスタンプです。今は2022年5月なので、それを`t`でフォーマットすると31ということになり、`date`の返値は`2022-6-31`となります。

`date`の2番めの引数として、$year年$month月のUnixタイムスタンプを与える必要があります。したがって以下のようになります。

```
<?php
$year = 2022;
$month = 6;
$start_date = date($year."-".$month."-01");
$end_date = date("Y-n-t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
echo $end_date;
```